# How do I setup DNS to use Google Apps for email, but my existing hosting account for the website?

Tags: gmail, dns, google-sites

I'm using name.com for my domain names and also using them for DNS management. I enabled google sites for my domain. The good part is I can now visit mail.example.com and my Google Sites mail client comes up. Sweet. The bad part is that it's now displaying the Google Sites version of my page.

I have some A, MX, and CNAME records in the DNS. The A recs are all set to some IP addresses, the MX recs are all set to subdomains of google.com, and my 4 CNAME records (docs, calendar, mail, www) point to ghs.google.com.

I'd like to set this up so that people could visit example.com and get my website, which is already built and living on a hosting provider's server. I'd also like to get this if a person typed in www.example.com. Only for mail.example.com, docs.example.com, and calendar.example.com do I want to send them to the Google App.

Any help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: Unless you specifically mapped the DNS entry for your main domain name to Google, it shouldn't be doing that (AFAIK). When you say Google Sites, I think in some instances you mean Google Apps; it's a little confusing. The way to troubleshoot this might be to provide the domain name in question so we can look at what's actually happening. (This question might be better for Server Fault, but I haven't any idea on move policies.)

Comment: Just set the cname www.name.com to  name.com.

Comment: yeah i wasn't sure if this question belongs here or on server fault. If there's some way to move questions point me in the right direction.

Answer (score 1):

Set a A record for each of different servers IP, for example for example.com and docs.example.com and CNAME records pointing to the right server for the other ones. www.example.com CNAME to example.com, calendar.example.com CNAME to docs.example.com and so on. Everything in A records would work too if possible to do.

To correct from I can get of the question, I think it's only changing the record for www.example.com to point to example.com if from what I understood, example.com is going to the right place.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for all your answers, they were all pretty good tips. I've just got this worked out and I'll tell you what I did.

Through name.com's DNS management, there's an option to "Enable Google Apps" (yes Apps not Sites, there's differences). This basically writes out 3 A records to google servers, 5 MX records to google mail servers, and 4 CNAME records to ghs.google.com (docs,calendar,mail,www).

I had to clear out the 3 A records and add three of my own rules mapping example.com, @.example.com, and www.example.com to the IP address for my web server. Then I deleted the www CNAME record pointing to ghs.google.com. Everything is working.